# Is it okay to ask questions pertaining to the aesthetics of mathematical symbols?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm fed up with the infinity glyph. For instance, when it's used to denote an interval like $[0,\infty),$ the infinity symbol is clearly not tall enough, and its far too elongated; it just doesn't fit with the rest of the number glyphs.

I want to ask people for ideas/preferences on alternative symbols (not in the sense of a different typeface, but in the sense of a different symbol altogether, like $\omega$, for example), but I don't know if this is the right site to do it on.

Acceptable, or not?

Comment: Maybe it would be OK to ask for other notations that have been used... In this case: $[0,+\infty[$ or $[0,\rightarrow)$, etc.

Comment: I cannot get enough of the infinity glyph, I find it smooth, friendly, relaxing, each time my eyes fall on its elongation, the sun begins to shine in my heart... Ad lib. Then, what do we do?

Answer (score 6):

This would be an example of a question which would fit the following closure criteria:

> **not constructive**
>   As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format.  We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. ...

I would vote to close such a question.

Answer (score 4):

Besides what has already been said, the [FAQ states that](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) you shouldn't ask quesitons where

`every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”`
or

`there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”`

I would say that your question falls into these categories of questions.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that typography or notation are purely subjective as some answers seem to imply. But MSE is not the right place to discuss typography and I don't think there is much point in finding viable alternatives for symbols used as commonly.

Comment: I think asking about _preferences_ for alternatives is subjective, however.

Comment: @Arthur Point taken.

Comment: If it is supposed about typography, [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) and [Graphic Design beta](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) both have typography tag; so those site might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I fear that such a discussion (not here, but on MO) would be useless, since even if we agree to use a different symbol we would not able to persuade the mathematical community as a whole to change their habits. Neither $\omega$ nor $\aleph_0$ are good choices, btw.